# SQL aggregate function in n:m relationship

Tags: sql, entity-relationship

The domain is an airline booking system. Users can book a flight. A flight consists of one or more legs.

```
  ┌─────┐        ┌──────┐      ┌───────┐
  │ Leg ├────────┤Flight├──────┤Booking│
  └─────┘  *   * └──────┘1   * └───────┘
```

To show the user a list of valid flights, the system must find out if a flight has free seats available. Maximum available seats are stored as field in the `Leg` table. Booked seats are stored in `Booking`.

Flights may consist of multiple legs. For example there might be 3 legs A -> B -> C. And two flights that should be bookable by the users:

1. A -> B: Flight from A to B.
2. A -> B -> C: Flight from A to C via B.

I have created a [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hRXosp353y2DbKJS6fNk4P/2) with a try of grouping by legs which gives me the number of booked seats per leg. But I need to generate a list of flights with the highest number of booked passengers per leg. In the example above: Flight 1 might have less available seats, if passengers are booked on Flight 2, because they both "share" the first leg.

```
select l.id as Leg, sum(b.number_passengers) as BookedSeats
FROM flight f
     JOIN flight_legs fl on f.id = fl.flight_id
     JOIN leg l on fl.legs_id = l.id
     JOIN booking b on f.id = b.flight_id
GROUP BY l.id;
```

How can I create a list of flights with available seats?

### Example

#### Schema

Leg

| id | seats_available |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 |

Flight

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |

Flight_Leg

| flight_id | leg_id | legs_order |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 |

*Note: Flight 1 has two legs and Flight 2 only one leg. Both flights "share" the same first leg.*

Booking

| id | flight_id | number_passengers |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |

*Note: One person booked flight 1 and flies both legs. Another person booked flight 2 with only the first leg. This means, two passengers on the first leg and one passenger on the remaining leg.*

#### Expected output

*Find all flights with available seats. Seats might be consumed by legs of other flights, too.*

| flight_id | free_seats |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 |

*Note: Flight 2 has no free seat, because the first leg is fully booked*

### ER Diagram

[image]

Comment: Enter your desired output and sample data if possible

Comment: @LucasEthen Added an explanation of the dbfiddle example.

Answer (score 0):

The following query implements your desired output. I used the `Lag` function to go to the previous row if the previous leg was full.

```
SELECT Leg,
   case
     when Free_Seats = 0 then 0 
        else (case when PrevLeg = 0 then 0 else Free_Seats end) end as Free_Seats

FROM (SELECT Leg,Free_Seats,LAG(Free_Seats,1) OVER(ORDER BY Leg) PrevLeg
  FROM (SELECT l.id AS Leg,l.seats_available,b.number_passengers,fl.flight_id,
             (max(l.seats_available) OVER(PARTITION BY fl.flight_id) - sum(b.number_passengers) OVER(PARTITION BY fl.flight_id)) AS Free_Seats,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY fl.flight_id ORDER BY fl.flight_id) AS seq
         FROM flight f
          JOIN flight_legs fl ON f.id = fl.flight_id
          JOIN leg l ON fl.legs_id = l.id
          JOIN booking b ON f.id = b.flight_id) T
 WHERE t.seq=1) T
```

Comment: Thank you. This gives me free seats per leg. But I need free seats **per flight**.

Comment: I understand, but your desired output is wrong because flight_id = 1 has two leg records and a total of four seats, of which two seats are left.

Comment: Then I was not clear with my example: The first leg has 1 passenger from Booking 1 (booked Flight 1) and 1 passenger from Booking 2 (booked Flight 2). Therefore Flight 1 should give 0 free seats because the first leg has two persons booked (but for different flights). Flight 2 should also give 0 free seats, because the first leg is full, although on the second leg a free seat would be available. Updated the expected output.

Comment: I implemented your output. I hope it is according to your request.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work: No matter how many seats are set for leg1 free_seats are always 0 ([demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c297efea01c9ced165f3401bdc8b9315)). And it does not give my free seats by flight. Instead it gives free seats by leg.

Comment: I changed the query. It is grammatically correct, but logically I may not have understood the question correctly.

Comment: The use case is to show bookable Flights to users. The end user is not interested in Legs - only in Flights. A Flight is bookable if on **every** flight's leg seats are available. The problem is, that legs are shared by multiple flights. So to find out if a Flight is bookable, the SQL must find all Legs of the Flight and then join all Flights that use these legs with all Bookings.